# fade effect with Gstreamer textoverlay element

Tags: gstreamer

I want the gstreamer textoverlay element to render text with a fade-in/fade-out effect.  The released version does not do this.  Does anyone know of a fork or a similar plugin that can do this?

Comment: This seems better for another stackexchange site.

Comment: I searched Stack Exchange for "gstreamer textoverlay fade effect" but most of the posts were either on stackoverflow or askubuntu and one on superuser.  Looks like the answer to my question is "no".